# iText header: add logo img on the left side and text on the right side

Tags: image, header, itext

I´m new to `iText`.
I would like to make a header that will be the same on each page.
The page header will look something like this:

```
logo.jpg                                                                       some text
```

How can I do that?
I have read this link:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-generate-report-dynamic-header-pdf-using-itextsharp

and I have a problem because I cant add an image to pharse.

```
Image image = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(mclLogo));
phrase.Add(image);
```

Throws the Error:

> Insertion of illegal Element: 32

Edit: I have tried with paragraph and glue:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Add(image);
paragraph.Add(new Chunk(glue));
paragraph.Add("text on the right");
```

and the output is 2 lines.
somthing link this:

```
logo.jpg
                                                                                some text
```

edit 2:
I have read this:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-1-introducing-basic-building-blocks
espacially the part:

```
Image fox = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(FOX));
Image dog = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(DOG));
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("The quick brown ")
        .add(fox)
        .add(" jumps over the lazy ")
        .add(dog);
document.add(p);
```

but I use iText5 and I dont find any way how to make a picture and text in the same line.

Comment: The error explains that you can't add an `Image` to a `Phrase`. Why don't you browse the [official FAQ](http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions)?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : I know that what it means. I didnt find any explanation how to do it correctly, not in the examples, not the tutorials and not the faq.
I have tried to add with a paragraph and glue, the output of the text and the image isn't on the same line

Comment: Why are you pretending you are helpless? That is bad for your Karma. Use a `PdfPTable` as described in [How to add a text to the left and to the right in a header?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-left-and-right-header) Instead of adding text to the right, add an `Image` to the `PdfPCell` as described in [How to resize an Image to fit it into a PdfPCell?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-resize-image-fit-it-pdfpcell) There are other examples in the FAQ that would work too.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: As I said, I am new.
I think I found my problem but I still cant fixed it. I didnt add the image correctly. I need to do it with "new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create "
but for some reason I dont find the correct library to add that it wont throw a compilation error

Comment: PS. I use iTextSharp

Comment: It should be very easy to convert Java code to C#. Note that Stack Overflow is meant for *specific* technical problems. Stack Overflow doesn't replace a proper education. Please learn more about iText and iTextSharp before posting a question. Right now, it sounds as if you want someone to do your work in your place.

Answer (score 0):

> Try below code, which works with two different Header plot which plotted at right end with image and Left end one with text.

```
public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
{
        PdfPTable HeaderPlot = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 10F });//Header plot 1
        PdfPTable HeaderPlot2 = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 10F });//Header plot 2
        PdfPCell cell;//cell 1
        PdfPCell cell2;// cell 2
        HeaderPlot.TotalWidth = 570F; //width for Header plot 1
        HeaderPlot2.TotalWidth = 570F;//width for Header plot 2
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell2 = new PdfPCell();
        string path = headerpath;
        FileInfo f2 = new FileInfo(path);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(f2.FullName,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] fileData = rdr.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        Image image = Image.GetInstance(fileData);
        image.ScaleAbsolute(80, 40); //adjusting image size
        image.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell = new PdfPCell(image)
        {
            Border = 0,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP,
            VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP
        };//Header image position
        Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri Light", 8f, Font.NORMAL, 
        iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK);//Initializing font
        cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Text", font))
        {
            Border = 0,
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP
        };//Header Text position
        HeaderPlot.AddCell(cell);//adding cell 1 to Headerplot 1
        HeaderPlot.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 480, 835, 
        writer.DirectContent);//Position of the header on right end, coordinates on right end(480,835)
        HeaderPlot2.AddCell(cell2);//adding cell 2 to Headerplot 2
        HeaderPlot2.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, 835, 
        writer.DirectContent);//Position of the header on left end, coordinates on left end(40,835)
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing here and why it works? A bunch of code with no explanation isn't really helpful to anyone.

Comment: @rubyandcoffee I have added the explanation, please check :)